Not successfully rendering state change after navigate() with react-router-dom
I have a problem with rendering a component after a performing a navigate with state to another page. Everything works as expected when I am already on the page that I am navigating to, but I would like for it to work when I navigate from another page as well.
I have a "globally" defined keyboard listener that should navigate me to the desired page upon a sequence of keys (I'm using a barcode scanner).
const barcodeString = useRef("")
const recordingBarcode = useRef(false)

const scannerCallback = useCallback(
    (e) => {
        if (e.key === "$") {
            recordingBarcode.current = true;
        } else if (e.key === "Enter" && recordingBarcode.current) {
            recordingBarcode.current = false;
            navigate("/box/build", {state:{barcode:barcodeString.current}});
            barcodeString.current = ""
        } else if (recordingBarcode.current) {
            barcodeString.current = barcodeString.current + e.key;
        }
    },
    [],
);

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', scannerCallback);

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keydown', scannerCallback);
    };
}, [scannerCallback]);

If I press the sequence "$4Enter" it successfully navigates to the "/box/build" page
                <Route path='/box/build'
                   element={<BuildBoxPage buildBoxRequest={buildBoxRequest}
                                          getRecipesRequest={getRecipesRequest}
                   />}/>

In the BuildBoxPage I do the following
const BuildBoxPage = ({buildBoxRequest, getRecipesRequest}) => {
const {state} = useLocation();
const [box, setBox] = useState();
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([]);
const [boxNumber, setBoxNumber] = useState();
const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
const [supplements, setSupplements] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (state != undefined) {
        updateBox(state.barcode)
    }
}, [state]);

const updateBox = (barcode) => {
    setBoxNumber(barcode);
    // == to compare a string value with an int on purpose
    setBox(boxes.find(box => box.box_number == barcode));
}

const fetchBoxes = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch('/food/box/v1/boxes', {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                ContentType: "application/json"
            },
        });
        const data = await res.json();
        setBoxes(data.boxes);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching boxes", error);
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchBoxes();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await getRecipesRequest();
            const data = await res.json();
            setRecipes(data.recipes);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error fetching recipes", error);
        }
    }
    fetchRecipes();
}, []);
...
}

This updates the select with the state value (boxNumber) that I am using for choosing a box, but doesn't render the the BuildBoxForm component in response to choosing a select value.
    return (<section className="bg-indigo-50 min-h-[calc(100vh-81px)]">
    <div className="container m-auto max-w-2xl py-10">
        <div
            className="bg-white px-6 py-8 mb-4 shadow-md rounded-md border m-4 md:m-0"
        >
            <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <h2 className="text-3xl text-center font-semibold mb-6">Build box</h2>
                <div className="mb-4">
                    <label className="block text-gray-700 font-bold mb-2"
                    >Box Number</label
                    >
                    <select
                        id="boxNumber"
                        name="boxNumber"
                        className="border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 mb-2"
                        required
                        value={boxNumber}
                        defaultValue={"def"}
                        onChange={(e) => updateBox(e.target.value)}
                    >
                        <option hidden value={"def"}>Select a box to build</option>
                        {boxes.map((box) => (
                            <option key={box.box_number} value={box.box_number}>{box.box_number}</option>
                        ))}
                    </select>
                </div>
                {
                    box !== undefined ?
                        <BuildBoxForm box={box} recipe={recipes[box.recipe_number - 1]} ingredients={ingredients}
                                      setIngredients={setIngredients} supplements={supplements}
                                      setSupplements={setSupplements}/> : <></>
                }
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>)

The result is the following if I am on the same page while navigating. This is the expected result and also the result I get if I manually select a box number in the select.

This is what I get if I am on another page while navigating, note that the number does update in the select but the BuildBoxForm is not rendered (because box is still undefined).

Any ideas of where I am going wrong here?

After giving this some more thought I realised that my problem might happen because the boxes have not yet loaded in, so I'm setting an undefined box. Will check if this is the issue.

Your post title and body don't match. The title implies an issue passing routing state. I don't see any overt issues with the passing of the barcode value in the routing state, it should be there and available in the BuildBoxForm component. The post body implies you've some additional issue later on picking a box or something. The [mcve] is incomplete and the post is missing details. Please [edit] to clarify what the specific problem is you need help with.

Nowhere in the title do I mention issues passing the state. It clearly states that there are issues rendering this state change.

Edited to include missing useEffect statements.

Then I disagree about the clarity. My interpretation was the "state" was related to the navigate call. If this isn't the case then please [edit] the post and title to omit/downplay the irrelevant details about passing the barcode value, and include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant BuildBoxPage component code.

Turns out the issue was related to boxes and recipes not yet being populated through useEffect as I was trying to set the box after navigating. The solution was to add a dependency on these two states and setting the box only if these two have been set.
    useEffect(() => {
    if (state != undefined && boxes.length > 0 && recipes.length > 0) {
        updateBox(state.barcode)
    }
}, [state, boxes, recipes]);

